# Open source URL shortening software?

Tags: open-source, url-shortener

Are there any open source [URL shortening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) software projects out there? Perhaps something that works in conjunction with Apache?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of them popped up when I did a search on Github:

https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=url+shortener&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories

Answer (score 5):

Does this Count? http://code.google.com/p/urly/

or this http://yourls.org/

Comment: The liver version is read only due to changes in the google API. So this may not be usable any more.

Answer (score 3):

Firefly claims it can be up & running in 2 minutes: https://github.com/ariejan/firefly#readme

Here are some other suggestions: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/7-open-source-and-free-url-shortener-scripts-to-create-your-own/

Answer (score 2):

You could do it yourself easily enough with a database. Just store each long url in the database as a key and the short one as a value. You could easily create a short one with an auto-increment field in your table. Your urls would look like this:

http://mysite.com/12345

In your server side programming language of choice, just do a look up into the table, and then do a redirect.

Comment: Naturally. I'm hoping to not re-invent the wheel. Or at least get a good look at some existing wheels, first.

Answer (score 2):

I use http://yourls.org/ in my shortener, very powerful and plugin enabled. You can also easily create your own pages with stats and stuff.

Here's mine:

http://impbr.com